# Passing selected layer-feature inside QgisAlgorithm (in code)

Tags: pyqgis, features, algorithm, input

In our algorithm, we do three steps:

1. call Algorithm A `AlgoA`,
2. `takeResultLayer` into `lyr` from `AlgoA` output,
3. for each feature of `lyr` we want to `run` Algorithm B `AlgoB` .

Code of my processAlgorithm looks like this:

```py
       alg_params = {
            'Input': parameters['INPUT'],
            'native:intersection_1:OUT': 'memory:'
        }
        zta  = processing.run('model:AlgoA', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)['native:intersection_1:OUT']
    
        lyr = context.takeResultLayer(zta)  
        features = lyr.getFeatures()
    
        for i, f in enumerate(features):
             # FeaturesIntersectionOperation
            alg_params = {
                'One_Feature': f,
                'native:intersection_1:out': 'memory:'
            }
    
            out = processing.run('model:AlgoB', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)['native:intersection_1:out']
```

The error I get is:

> Unable to execute algorithm Could not load source layer for
> One_Feature: invalid value

If I pass an entire layer `lyr` as `'One_Feature': lyr` it all runs Ok. If I use my algorithm from QGis UI with iterate over layer features selected  like this:
[image]
it also runs Ok.

So how to implement for each layer feature inside QGIS 3+ `processAlgorithm` script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
        for i, f in enumerate(features):
             # FeaturesIntersectionOperation
            alg_params = {
                'One_Feature': f,
                'native:intersection_1:out': 'memory:'
            }
    
            out = processing.run('model:AlgoB', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)['native:intersection_1:out']
```

do

```
        # List features ids from layer
        ids = [f.id() for f in features]
        # Loop to select by id the layer
        for id in ids:
            lyr.selectByIds([id])
            # Use the selected layer with the following (see https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsProcessingFeatureSourceDefinition.html#qgis.core.QgsProcessingFeatureSourceDefinition for params)
            sourceDef = QgsProcessingFeatureSourceDefinition(lyr.id(), True)
            # FeaturesIntersectionOperation
            alg_params = {
                'One_Feature': sourceDef,
                'native:intersection_1:out': 'memory:'
            }
    
            out = processing.run('model:AlgoB', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)['native:intersection_1:out']
```

Comment: Sadly getting same Could not load source layer for One_Feature: output_32b4b3b6_f977_4ffd_9d19_5e366c1e0c41 not found error

Comment: How did you define your `model:AlgoB`? In particular what does `processing.algorithmHelp("model:AlgoB")` returns? Depending of your algo, our approach could be wrong (for both of us)